# Hiding a SwiftUI View from another SwiftUI View

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui

I'd like to perform an action to hide elements on my screen when a button is tapped using SwiftUI.

So for example, let's say I have 2 images, a text, and a button on my screen.

If I tap the button I want the other elements to animate off-screen. Tap the button again and they animate back onto the screen.

Each element is created in their own View which is in its own file. Is there a way to access a View from another View?

Here's an example:

```
struct buttonView : View {

    @State private var isShowingImageView = false

    @Binding var myImage: ImageView

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
                    self.isShowingImageView.toggle()
                }) {
                    HStack(spacing: 18) {
                        Image("button-icon")
                        Text("Press Me")
                    }

                }

            if isShowingImageView {
                myImage.hidden()
            }
    }

}
```

My image is created in its own struct / View and when I press the button I want to hide that image.

Right now it's not hiding it, just the view my button is in animates a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sam has stated already you could use a combination of `@State` and `@Binding`.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var show = true

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            View1(show: $show)
            View2(show: $show)
        }
    }
}

struct View1: View {

    @Binding var show: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if show {
                Text("Text1")
            }

            Text("Text2")
        }
    }
}

struct View2: View {

    @Binding var show: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Text3")

            if show {
                Text("Text4")
            }

            Button(action: {
                self.show.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Toogle show")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

From your master/root view, you can create `@State` variables that you pass into the subviews as `@Binding` variables.

I can't give you more specifics without seeing your code, but it *is* possible.